# Checking user's reputation by PHP vs MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

I have a question-and-answer website *(something like SO)*. I want to implement this condition:

> **Condition:** An user can give a vote-down who has at least 125 reputatoin.

Well I can implement that condition in two ways:

**Server Side:** When user log in, I get his reputation and set it into `$_SESSION['rep']`. Then use it before *commenting*

```
if( $_SESSION['rep'] >= 125 ) { /* can vote */ } else { /* cannot vote */ }
```

**Database Side:** I can use a trigger and check it like this:

```
IF ( SELECT 1 FROM user WHERE id = new.user_id AND rep < 125) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "cannot vote";
END if;`
```

---

I have tested both of them and they work as well. Now I want to know which one is more common and standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I've been using the Database Side approach all the time (not by using a trigger but by querying the database before commenting and checking user's reputation in PHP). It will not slow down the performance too much.

However, if you really need the performance to be good, you may cache user reputation in memory (don't use $_SESSION, it will easily lead to inconsistency problems). What about using Redis/Memcached? When the user logs in, put his/her reputation in the cache. When the user's reputation is updated in the database, update(invalidate) the cache too. When you need to figure out whether the user has the permission to down vote, you just need to consult your cache, no db query involved.

P.S. They key of the cache should look like `user_rep_5` (where 5 is the user_id), not `user_rep_xxxx` (where xxxx is the session id). I mean, the cache should be done globally to make sure there is only one single source of truth, instead of associating it with the session.

Comment: There's no need to check first. You can check on INSERT, which saves a trip to the database. But really it's about managing the user experience in the way that you want - so perhaps the vote button is greyed out or invisible until the rep is attained.

Comment: @Strawberry yeah if you don't care about user experience (greying out/hiding the button) just check before insert I agree

Comment: You said *"just check before insert"*, Should I check that by what? PHP or MySQL?

Comment: @Shafizadeh Check it with PHP, put it in your business logic. If you use backend template rendering, check user privilege before showing the down vote button. In other words, don't print the HTML of the down vote button if the user doesn't have privilege to vote. (For better user experience) Also, check with PHP before actually doing the insert. If the check fails, print an error message and abort (For security). I'm not a fan of database triggers so I always do checking in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Before this step

```
if( $_SESSION['rep'] >= 125 ) { /* can vote */ } else { /* cannot vote */ }
```

Its better if you update `$_SESSION['rep']` and checked with that updated reputation.

Comment: So why not `TRIGGER`? I can check it by a `TRIGGER` instead of *updating* and checking by PHP.

Answer (score -2):

Doing it on Server Side is a better option. You can get his reputation when you the user logs in and just need to validate before he answers.

When you are doing it on database side, you are doing one extra call and that too making the user wait for the response from the DB Server. This will slow you.

Comment: I disagree. Because if the user has more than 125rep and logs and then lose all his rep, still he can give downvote, because `$_SESSION['rep']` doesn't change.