# MySQL syntax (function) is error

Tags: mysql, function, syntax-error

```
CREATE FUNCTION FC_IDKRITERIA()
RETURNS CHAR(3)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @MAX INT , @KODEBARU CHAR(3)  
SELECT @MAX = MAX (RIGHT(IDKRITERIA,2)) FROM KRITERIA
IF @MAX IS NULL 
SET @MAX = 0
SET @KODEBARU = 'K' + RIGHT('0'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),@MAX+ 1 ) ,2)
RETURN @KODEBARU
END
```

Comment: You're missing `;` at the end of each statement.

Answer (score 2):

Every statement in a procedure must end with `;`. To keep this from ending the function definition, use the `DELIMITER` command to change the command delimiter to something else.

And when doing a variable assignment in a `SELECT` clause, you have to use `:=`.

There's no `AS` at the beginning of a function definition.

You don't declare variables that begin with `@`.

You need `THEN` and `END IF` in an `IF` statement.

To concatenate strings, use `CONCAT()`, not `+`.

You have the arguments to `CONVERT()` in the wrong order, and `VARCHAR(3)` is not a valid type argument, it should be `CHAR(3)`.

In a function, you can't use a `SELECT` statement at the top-level, because that means to return the result set, and functions can only return single values. So you have to assign `@MAX` from a `(SELECT ...)` expression.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION FC_IDKRITERIA() RETURNS CHAR(3)
BEGIN
    SET @MAX = (SELECT MAX (RIGHT(IDKRITERIA,2)) FROM KRITERIA);
    IF @MAX IS NULL 
    THEN SET @MAX = 0;
    END IF;
    SET @KODEBARU = CONCAT('K', RIGHT('0'+CONVERT(@MAX+ 1, CHAR(3)) ,2));
    RETURN @KODEBARU;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: ++ nice. Also as a consultation: I need to check user's reputation before insert his vote into `Votes` table. So should I do that *(checking)* in **Database-side** *(by a trigger)* or **Server-side** *(fetch user's rep when he logs and set it to session, then use that session for checking)* ?

Comment: @Shafizadeh You have an answer in your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096493/checking-users-reputation-by-php-vs-mysql/37097408#37097408

Comment: Yes you are right ..! Thx for your attention. btw I really stuck on [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160002/how-do-i-check-a-few-conditions-before-updating). To be honest I'm embarrassed to ping you again. But I promise this is the last one. So if you have some free time please take a look at it.

Comment: You had lots of other syntax errors, I've fixed them all in the updated answer.