# How can I use JOIN in UPDATE statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

I have a table like this:

```
// QandA
+----+----------------------------------------+---------+----------+-----------+
| Id |                   body                 | related | accepted | author_id |
+----+----------------------------------------+---------+----------+-----------+
| 1  | content of question1                   | null    | null     | 12345     |
| 2  | content of first answer for question1  | 1       | 0        | 53456     |
| 3  | content of question2                   | null    | null     | 43634     |
| 4  | content of second answer for question1 | 1       | 0        | 43665     |
| 5  | content of first answer for question2  | 3       | 1        | 43324     |
+----+----------------------------------------+---------+----------+-----------+

/* related column: Actually that's just for answers and this column is containing the id of
   its question. (questions always are null) */

/* accepted column: Actually that's just for answers and specifics accepted answer.
   0 means it isn't accepted answer, 1 means it is accepted answer.
   (questions always are null) */
```

---

I'm trying to implement this **condition** before setting the accepted answer for a question:

**Condition:** Validating whether current user is OP or not. `author_id of` its question should be the same as `$_SESSION['id']`.

---

Here is my query: *(all data I have is just the id of accepted answer `:answer_id`)*

```
UPDATE QandA q CROSS JOIN ( SELECT related FROM QandA WHERE id = :answer_id ) x
    SET accepted = ( id = :answer_id ) -- this acts like a if statement 
  WHERE q.related   = x.related
        AND
        -- validating OP
        (SELECT 1 FROM QandA 
          WHERE id = x.related AND
                author_id = $_SESSION['id']
        )
```

> **#1093** - You can't specify target table 'tbname' for update in FROM clause

How can I fix it?

---

**EDIT:** Actually there is one more condition:

```
+----+----------------------------------------+---------+----------+-----------+------+
| Id |                   body                 | related | accepted | author_id | free |
+----+----------------------------------------+---------+----------+-----------+------+
| 1  | content of question1                   | null    | null     | 12345     | null |
| 2  | content of first answer for question1  | 1       | 0        | 53456     | null |
| 3  | content of question2                   | null    | null     | 43634     | 300  |
| 4  | content of second answer for question1 | 1       | 0        | 43665     | null |
| 5  | content of first answer for question2  | 3       | 1        | 43324     | null |
+----+----------------------------------------+---------+----------+-----------+------+

/* free column: Actually that's just for questions. `null` means it is a free question
   and any number else means it isn't. (answers always are `null`) */
```

**Additional Condition:** If the question is free, then OP can accept an answer for it, and change his accepted answer, and undo his accepted answer. But if the question isn't free, then OP just can accept a question one time, and he cannot undo it, and he cannot change accepted answer. Here is implementing of that condition in MySQL:

```
(SELECT 1 FROM QandA
  WHERE id = x.related AND
        (
          ( free IS NOT NULL AND
            NOT IN ( SELECT 1 FROM QandA
                      WHERE related = x.related AND
                            accepted = 1 )
          ) OR free IS NULL
        )
)
```

Comment: Why are you attempting to implement all of this business logic in the database?  Better to use transactions and implement it within your application.

Comment: @eggyal those two validating are depend on database. I have to check *1.current user who is accepting an answer is the OP*? *2. if question isn't free, then OP can accept an answer just one time (he cannot undo or change accepted answer)*

Comment: So?  Select the data you wish to check into your application, then effect your desired logic.

Comment: @eggyal Do you mean by multiple queries?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: @eggyal Well I'll do that if I have to .. But I think validating those two conditions in one query is possible.

Comment: You can perform a self-join in an `UPDATE`, just as with a `SELECT`.  E.g. `UPDATE QandA question JOIN QandA answer ON question.id = answer.related SET answer.accepted = 1 WHERE answer.id = :answer_id AND question.free = 1 AND question.author_id = :session_id` etc.  I'm finding it pretty hard to follow all the logic in your question though, hence why I think it would be easier for you (and any future maintainer of your code) to see the steps split out.

Comment: @eggyal I've updated my question. If you have some free time please take a look at it.

Comment: Why are you using the same table for questions and answers? When you have columns that are "just for questions" or "just for answers", that's a strong indication that they should be in different tables.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, except you, a few other people told me I have to create two separated tables for questions and answers. But I've followed what so does, it also has one single tables for both questions and answers, you can see it [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/421098). Besides, I have no time to completely change tables-structure. Now I'm just looking for a workaround to validate current user *(who have sent a accepted-answer request)* is OP or not before updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
UPDATE QandA AS ans1
JOIN QandA AS ans2 ON ans2.related = ans1.related
JOIN QandA AS ques ON ans2.related = ques.id
SET ans1.accepted = (ans1.id = :answer_id)
WHERE ques.author_id = :session_id
AND ans2.id = :answer_id
```

The first `JOIN` filters down to the answers to the same question as the answer being accepted.

The second `JOIN` finds that question.

The `WHERE` clause will restrict the update only to questions with the given author and specifies the answer ID being accepted.

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe2ca5/1)

For the additional condition, add

```
AND (ques.free IS NULL or ans1.accepted IS NULL)
```

to the `WHERE` clause. `ques.free IS NULL` matches any free question, and `ans1.accepted IS NULL` matches a question with no accepted answer (because when an answer is accepted, all the other answers to that question get `accepted = 0`).

[DEMO of question with no accepted answer](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eaaf8/1)
[DEMO of question that's free](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7d13/1)

Comment: Look, your answer is great and I'm trying to change your query and make my own query based on the needs in reality, but I cannot. I've edited my question and added a new condition which should be implemented in the query too. If you can do that, I appreciate you very much, otherwise no problem, still I will accept your answer as accepted.

Comment: What does `free = 300` mean? The comment says it can be either `NULL` or `1`.

Comment: I've edited that comment which explains what's `300`. btw your new update is correct and incomplete. If I add `AND ques.free IS NULL` in the `WHERE` clause, then OP isn't able to accept an answer **for non-free** questions at all. while expected condition is: OP can accept an answer for non-free question just **once** *(one time)* not more *(OP cannot undo or change it)*. So I think I have to add an `OR` operator to the condition.

Comment: Something like this: `... AND ( ques.free IS NULL OR (ques.free IS NOT NULL AND ans1.accepted NOT IN ( 1 ) ) )`. but [it doesn't work](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d401bd/1)

Comment: I changed it to `AND (ques.freee IS NULL OR ans1.accepted IS NULL)`. Just testing for `accepted = 1` won't work because one of the other answers might be accepted, and you said he can't change which answer is accepted. So the initial value of `accepted` needs to be `NULL` when no answer has been accepted.

Comment: unfortunately this new condition doesn't work. It never update non-free questions. I mean OP cannot accept an answer for non-free questions, even if there isn't any accepted answer so far.

Comment: Odd .. your new condition makes no sense but the new demo works as well. Also doesn't work in reality ..! I'm confused ... thx anyway

Comment: Ok look, forget that query, just tell me how can I understand whether is there an accepted answer or not? `ans1.accepted IS NULL` means there isn't any accepted answer?

Comment: I had the condition right the first time. I've made demos of both cases.

Comment: Now this condition seems completely correct and your explanations make sense. And your demos work correctly. But in reality nothing updates when question isn't free. The only difference between your demo and reality is datatype of `accepted` column. mine is `bit` and yours is `int`, is that important?

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference. Make sure it allows `NULL` and this is the default value.

Comment: The question is not free, and `accepted` is not null, so the accepted answer can't be changed.

Comment: That's the question, but `accepted` is only for answers. All the answers have `accepted = 0`. Change them to `NULL` and it should work.

Comment: Well played ... As you said *"Make sure it allows NULL and this is the default value"* ..! Got it .. Thank you man `:-)`

Comment: Just as a consult, to make **undo** an accepted answer *(just for free questions)*, I XOR it with `1` *(datataype of accepted column is `bit(1)`)*. and it works perfectly. I just want to know am I right? I will not faced with a problem later?

Comment: Why don't you just `SET accepted = 0`? If you XOR all the answers to a question with 1, that will toggle them all. But then you may get more than one accepted answer, which probably isn't right.

Comment: I mean something like this: `SET IF (ans1.id <> :answer_id, null, SET ans1.accepted ^ b'1')`  . . . That `null` also can be `0`.

Comment: It should be `SET ans1.accepted = (IF ans1.id <> :answer_id, NULL, ans1.accepted ^ b'1')`

Comment: You know what? all fine. That query works as expected and it checks two conditions as I wanted. Just a small thing, The result of `NULL ^ b'1'` is still `NULL`. I mean if default value be `NULL`, then it never change to `1` *(as accepted answer)*. Can you see my point?