# How to use both SELECT and UPDATE statements in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this `update` query which works as well:

```
UPDATE tbname t CROSS JOIN ( SELECT related FROM tbname WHERE id = 5 ) x
    SET AcceptedAnswer = ( id = 5 )
  WHERE t.related   = x.related
```

I also have two select statements which validates somethings. Actually I want to check these to conditions before updating:

**Condition1:**

```
(SELECT 1 FROM tbname 
  WHERE id = x.related AND
        author_id = 29
)
```

**Condition2:**

```
(SELECT 1 FROM tbname
  WHERE id = x.related AND
       (
          ( amount IS NOT NULL AND
            NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tbname
                           WHERE related = x.related AND
                                 AcceptedAnswer = 1 )
          ) OR amount IS NULL
       )
)
```

How can I combine those two conditions with that updating query?

---

Here is what I've tried so far but it doesn't work and throws this error:

```html
UPDATE tbname CROSS JOIN ( SELECT related FROM tbname WHERE id = 5 ) x
SET AcceptedAnswer = ( id = 5 )
  WHERE q.related   = x.related
    AND
    (SELECT 1 FROM tbname 
      WHERE id = x.related AND
            author_id = 29
    ) AND
    (SELECT 1 FROM tbname
      WHERE id = x.related AND
            (
              ( amount IS NOT NULL AND
                NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tbname
                               WHERE related = x.related AND
                                     AcceptedAnswer = 1 )
              ) OR amount IS NULL
            )
    )
```

> #1093 - You can't specify target table 'tbname' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Maybe subqueries? Or you could resolve it via triggers that check your conditions, or maybe even a stored procedure...

Comment: check this out ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server

Comment: @LalitMehra What you linked is sql server, mine is mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Seems your update is equivalent to this

```
update tbname as a
inner join tbname as b on a.related = b.related and b.id = 5
set AcceptedAnswer = (id =  5)
```

your query seem set to true  (1) the AccepetdAnswer of the row with id = 5  for the row that have acceppeted equalt  to the accepted value of th row with id = 5 (false / 0) in the other case  ..

for test use

```
select * from  tbname as a
inner join tbname as b on a.related = b.related and b.id = 5
and (b.related = a.id and a.author_id = 29)
and (b.related = a.id and 
          (a.amont is not null and (a.related = b.related and a.AcceptedAnswer = 1)))
```

Comment: Your simple update query isn't the same as mine. Mine sets both `1` for accepted answers and `0` for other answers of the question. *(for changing accepted answer or even undo it)* ..! btw my question is about implementing two conditions before updating.

Comment: Twell  i removed the second conclusion and i think the first is right ...this is just for rewrite the firts part of your query removing subselect ..

Comment: Yes, using an `inner join` instead of `cross join` seems correct in your solution. Just may you please tell me how can I add those two conditions in the query? I want if those tow conditions return `1` then updating applies otherwise updating fails.

Comment: how the two condition are related  to the firts part of the query ?

Comment: The firts mean and the id equals to  x.related and author_id  =  29?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160002/how-do-i-check-a-few-conditions-before-updating) is all I'm trying to do.

Comment: ***#1054** - Unknown column 'a.aumont' in 'on clause'*

Comment: ***#1052** - Column 'AcceptedAnswer' in on clause is ambiguous*. I can debug this, But I want you do that, because that's your query and you know what you have done so far ..!

Comment: Well not there isn't any error, but it doesn't match any row `:-)`. Anyway thanks for your try and showing me how can I do that by joining. upvote

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pretty sure what is the purpose of the SET clause (id =5) 
anyway this way avoids the use of the cross join provided that you
don't use the table "x" to get something beyond the "related" items.

```
UPDATE tbname 
SET 
    AcceptedAnswer = ( id = 5 )
WHERE  
    #THIS IS EQUIVALENT TO THE JOIN CLAUSE
    id IN ( SELECT related FROM tbname WHERE id = 5 )

    #THIS IS THE CONDITION 1 POINTING tnname    
    AND author_id = 29  

    #THIS IS THE CONDITION 2 POINTING tbname    
    AND ( 
     ( amount IS NOT NULL 
       AND NOT AcceptedAnswer = 1
     ) OR amount IS NOT NULL 
    )
;
```