# How to count how many doctors are booked by each patient?

Tags: php, mysql, count

I need the results to look like:

```
PatientID   Doctors
Patient1    3
Patient2    2
Patient3    1
```

The booked table looks like this

```
GPS Table

PatientID   DoctorID  DATE
Patient1    Doctor1   2016-02-16
Patient1    Doctor1   2016-04-08
Patient1    Doctor2   2016-06-09
Patient2    Doctor3   2017-01-02
Patient2    Doctor6   2016-12-01
Patient3    Doctor1   2016-07-12
```

There are more bookings, but I am just giving this table as an example.
Also I need to make sure that it would not count the same doctor if the person is booked 2 times for the doctor.

The code I have right now is:

```
select Bookings.PatientID, count(Bookings.DoctorID) as Doctors from Bookings where Bookings.DoctorID;
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Group by over a temp table with distinct patient and doctor

```
 select Patient, count(*)
 from (
 select distinct Bookings.PatientID as Patient ,DoctorID as Doctors 
 from Bookings  ) as t

 Group by Patient;
```

Comment: Nice .. +1 .. btw I've updated my question, if you have some free time please take a look at [it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160002/how-do-i-check-a-few-conditions-before-updating)

Comment: @Shafizadeh  please explain your new question  don't see where is cange d ... (but you are not the OP?..?)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `count(distinct)`:

```
select b.PatientID, count(distinct b.DoctorID) as NumDoctors
from Bookings b
group by b.PatientID;
```

Comment: distinct and group on the same column?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT PatientID, count(DoctorID) FROM `GPS ` group by PatientID
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked:

```
select PatientID as Patient, count(distinct(DoctorID)) as Doctors from Bookings, Patients group by PatientID;
```

Thank you for the help!